# Alternate formula for the determinant of a 3x3 Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

So, I've recently been reading about Dodgson condensation, for matrices. Take, in particular the $3x3$ case.

Define a matrix, $|A|:$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b & c \\
        d & e & f \\
        g & h & i \\
        \end{pmatrix}

By the process of condensation, $|A|$:
        \begin{pmatrix}
        \frac{ae-bd}{e} & \frac{bf-ce}{e} \\
        \frac{dh-eg}{e} & \frac{ei-fh}{e} \\
        \end{pmatrix}

And if denote $\det[A]=K$, then we can algebraically express $K$ in terms of $a,b,...,h,i$ by taking the determinant of this reduced $2x2$ matrix.

We can similarly do this with the normal process of finding the determinant, i.e.,: $\det[A]$:

$a\det\begin{pmatrix}
        e & f \\
        h & i \\
        \end{pmatrix} - b\det\begin{pmatrix}
        d & f \\
        g & i \\
        \end{pmatrix}+c\det\begin{pmatrix}
        d & e \\
        g & h \\
        \end{pmatrix}$

And then compare algebraic expressions between the two results. A lot of messy algebra and longford multiplication ensued, but I found, comparing the two methods that:

$\det[A]=K=\frac{2(bfg+cdh)}{1-e}$

Is this result, well known, pointless, or incorrect? Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you stating that the determinant of a $3\times 3$ matrix can be computed by that last formula? I would say it is incorrect. Take the identity matrix, for instance.

Comment: Also, the determinant of a $3 \times 3$ doesn't just depend on the non-zero-ness of the center element. Consider $[[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]$ which has determinant zero, but your formula does not even give a defined answer for its determinant.

Comment: Oh right, these are all good points. Forgot to run it through a quick common sense check. I thought something seemed a bit fishy...I'm going to revisit the math again. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: You might look at the Wikipedia page for "Dodgsons condensation method" (or a similar name, I just googled that and got to the wiki page). There it showed the method involves doing separate operations to make entries all nonzero at each stage, where those separate operations don't change the determinant. There are several worked examples.